# .env can't get read from inside a job

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, supervisord

I have a Laravel project (v8.12) running on PHP 7.4.3 in a dedicated AWS instance with Ubuntu  20.04. When I try to read an environment variable from inside a job, the value is always `null`, but it works elsewhere. I tried to switch from `supervisord` to `sync` driver, still couldn't reach it.

Comment: imo you only read .env variables from config files, and use the config helper to access the value anywhere in your application.

Comment: @GertB. I ended up doing that, the only thing that worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be from cache .
you can below commands for remove cache .

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear 

php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Tried, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Run below commands**

```
 composer dump-autoload

 php artisan clear-compiled
 php artisan optimize

 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan view:clear

 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan config:clear
```

**For Example**

In your env file

```
 SITE_NAME="My website"
```

Get your env variable like

```
 $data = env('SITE_NAME');   
 echo $data;
```

Comment: Tried these commands in the exact order, all environment variables are null.